# Cannot invoke tableViewController

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, uiviewcontroller, uinavigationcontroller

I've been struggling with switching viewControllers.

I got the following storyboard:

[image: storyboard]

The upper left VC is the login VC which pushes view to the MainViewController (bottom left) via a modal segue.

This works fine via:

```
self.performSegueWithIdentifier("MainSegue", sender: self)
```

MainViewController hosts a "Menu" bar item that when clicked initiates cocoa control SSASideMenu and presents LeftSideMenu VC. This also works fine.

LeftSideMenu VC has 2 menu items ("home" and "order"). Item "home" will go back to MainViewController (case 0 below - works fine). Item "order" needs to present ItemTableViewController (upper right) which is basically a tableVC with a prototype cell embedded in a navigation controller.

Case 1 below is where it all goes wrong:

```
func tableView(..........) {

    tableView.deselectRowAtIndexPath(indexPath,animated: true)

    switch (indexPath.row) {
        case 0: 
            sideMenuViewController?.contentViewController =
                UINavigationController(rootViewController: MainViewController())
            sideMenuViewController?.hideMenuViewController()
        break 
        case 1: 
            sideMenuViewController?.contentViewController =
                UINavigationController(rootViewController: ItemTableViewController())
            sideMenuViewController?.hideMenuViewController()
        break
    }
}
```

So, case 1 will result in func tableView of ItemTableViewController to be called:

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath ...) {

    let cellIdentifier = "MenuItemTableViewCell"
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier(cellIdentifier) as! MenuItemTableViewCell!

    let item = items[indexPath.row]

    cell.cellTitle.text = item.name // **cell is always nil**

    ....
```

cell is always nil.

I tried to register the class (even though I shouldn't have to since I am using storyboards) with:

```
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier(cellIdentifier) as! MenuItemTableViewCell!
    if cell == nil {
            tableView.RegisterClass(MenuItemTableViewCell.self, forCellReuseIdentifier: cellIdentifier)
            cell = MenuItemTableViewCell(style: UITableViewCellStyle.Default, reuseIdentifier: cellIdentifier)

    let item = items[indexPath.row]

    cell.cellTitle.text = item.name // **cell is still nil**
```

I also tried it with a segue but get the segue not exists on LeftSideMenu error (it does exists with the correct cellIdentifier).

Bottom line is I can't invoke ItemTableViewController (upper right tableVC)!

Any clues please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should never never never call `dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:`. Always use `dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:forIndexPath:` instead. It can *never* return a `nil` cell, and if there's trouble it will give you a nice error message explaining why.

What I expect will happen is that you'll get an error message telling you that aren't connected to the prototype cell in the storyboard. Then you have to figure out why. Getting the cell identifier correct is crucial, of course: it must match your code's reuse identifier *exactly*, including spelling. But there is much more to it than that. Perhaps you forgot to set the custom class of the table view controller in the storyboard. Or perhaps you have obtained the wrong instance of the table view controller - i.e., you made a new one rather than getting the actual instance from the storyboard, the instance that has the prototype cell.

Comment: I did use that initially. Error was 'unable to dequeue a cell with identifier MenuItemTableViewCell - must register a nib or a class for the identifier or connect a prototype cell in a storyboard'. I am using storyboard with the correct identifier though

Comment: But you see, that error is _helpful_. You were wrong to hide it from yourself by changing the call. :) This tells you that your connection between the table view controller and the storyboard is wrong. I don't know _what_ you've done wrong, but that is what you need to fix. Perhaps you forgot to set the custom class of the table view controller in the storyboard. Or perhaps you have obtained the wrong instance of the table view controller - i.e., you made a new one rather than getting the instance from the storyboard. That is the problem, but only you can see and fix it.

Comment: How would i get the tableVC storyboard instance though if it's never been instantiated before? It's the first call to the VC in the app.

Comment: You are saying this: `rootViewController: ItemTableViewController()`. That's the problem, just as I said. That's the wrong ItemTableViewController instance. It is a new and separate instance. You need _the instance in the storyboard_. You need to give the table view controller an identifier in the storyboard and get that instance _from the storyboard_ using the identifier.

Comment: Thank you Matt! Had to get the instance like this:let viewController:UIViewController = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil).instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("ViewController") as UIViewController. It worked great!